# How to simulate a Redis timeout in Unit Test using C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq, stackexchange.redis

I'm trying to write a Unit Test for StackExchange.Redis timeout (or simulate a StackExchange.Redis timeout). I'm using C# 4.7.1 and NUnit.Framework.
I was wondering if someone could provide some insights on this.

I came across this article which does same thing but in Node/Lua:
https://medium.com/@stockholmux/simulating-a-slow-command-with-node-redis-and-lua-efadbf913cd9

What I want is by running the unit test, StackExchange.Redis would time out and output the time out error message.

Comment: encapsulate and concrete implementations behind abstractions you can mock to behave as desired when testing. Since you have not shown any code there is not much else that I can suggest.

Comment: I haven't had any experience/exposure with StackExchange.Redis at all. I know how to setup 'TestFixture' and 'Test' in a class, but I don't honestly know what to do for Redis timeout. And that's why I don't have any code!